# Getting an iOS application's "~/Library" path reliably

Tags: ios, filesystems, documents

This Apple tech note:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1699.html

suggests storing "internal" user documents in a subdirectory off of `~/Library`. But I can't find one of the pre-created search domains that would get me this. What's the best/most correct/least likely to ever break way of constructing this path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The correct way is

```
NSString* path;
path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
```

However, `[@"~/Library" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]` also works.

---

Swift 3:

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
```

Comment: NSlibraryDirectory is documented to point to the root /Library, not the user version. Are they semantically equivalent in this case?

Comment: I have confirmed that `NSLibraryDirectory` combined with `NSUserDomainMask` does the right thing here. Thanks Kenny.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try this:

```
[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library"]
```