# Rename resources in AppBundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

How can i programatically rename resources in AppBundle.Need to resave or rename the images which are stored in AppBundle with a user given name.

Comment: search first on net, don't ask simple one directly on stack, it will make ur programming concepts weeker...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app bundle is immutable, you may not change it. You would need to copy the files to the app's Documents folder or its [Library folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762941/getting-an-ios-applications-library-path-reliably).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
NSString* your_path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```