# Get size of NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to get the total size of `NSUserDefaults`? because what I know it saves everything in a `.plist` file. It shouldn't be too hard to find that file and then see how big it is.

Comment: this `.plist` file present inside `cache` folder.

Comment: The plist file is present under `AppDirectory/Library/Preferences/<BundleIdentifier>.plist`. Try to read the [attributes of this file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5743957/1407017).

Comment: @Amar is that folder inside iphone/iphone simulator?

Comment: Its your apps directory which gets created when you install it on device/simulator. On simulator the path of this is `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOS version>/Applications/3FC9264F-371B-4DFC-8714-2726E45B0D6F/Library/Preferences`

Comment: @Amar I followed your link and made this in Swift: `let fileAttr:NSDictionary = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath("AppDirectory/Library/Preferences/\(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier).plist", error: nil); let size = fileAttr.objectForKey(NSFileSize).longLongValue`But it crashes and doesnt find it. Both in simulator and device.

Comment: You should not hard code `AppDirectory` path ... need to do it programmatically and append the remaining path including the plist file name and extension. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3763050/1407017

Answer (score 5):

Try this code,

```
NSString* libraryDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* filepath = [libraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Preferences/%@.plist",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]]];
long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filepath error:nil][NSFileSize] longLongValue];
```

Code referenced from [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763050/1407017), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743856/finding-files-size/5743957#5743957) which I mentioned in my comments.

You may have to convert this to use in Swift.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Updated to Swift-4

```
static func getSizeOfUserDefaults() -> Int? {
    guard let libraryDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.libraryDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else {
        return nil
    }

    let filepath = "\(libraryDir)/Preferences/\(bundleIdentifier).plist"
    let filesize = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filepath)
    let retVal = filesize?[FileAttributeKey.size]
    return retVal as? Int
}
```

Comment: Is this size in bytes? bits? kb?

Comment: Hey @Alfi the documentation says the size is in bytes. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/fileattributekey/1416548-size If you option click on the .size property in Xcode, you can get this info.