# Getting an iOS application's “~/Library” path reliably in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the directory where I can create files and write logs to files in my swift app for iOS devices. I read here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763050/919280, that using Objective-C, there is a solution. I tried writing it in swift like this:

```
var appDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true)
```

But, NSLibraryDirectory and NSUserDomainMask do not seem to be present in Swift. What is the way to do this is Swift?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
var appDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
```

**Explanation**:
You can click on method and see it's declaration.

```
func NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(directory: NSSearchPathDirectory, domainMask: NSSearchPathDomainMask, expandTilde: Bool) -> [AnyObject]!
```

As you can see it takes `NSSearchPathDirectory` enum
and `NSSearchPathDomainMask` struct.

In swift, when you use enums, you don't need to specify enum type, you can use case values itself
`.LibraryDirectory` instead of `NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory`

**Swift 5**

Enums are lower-case now:

```
.libraryDirectory

.userDomainMask
```

Comment: Where is the conversion of NSLibraryDirectory to .LibraryDirectory (or similar) documented? I want to understand why one option begins with , and the other needs a namespace

Comment: see my edit's to answer. Xcode generate Swift header for all classes. 
if you click on NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains. 
it will show you Foundation->NSPatchUtilities file with Swift declarations

Comment: There is an Xcode bug that sometimes it can't show Swift classes when you click one method and want to see documentation. (It's because Swift is still in beta). Then try to restart Xcode, it helps sometimes

Comment: The second argument can also be shortened to `.UserDomainMask`

Comment: @KostiantynKoval is there a difference between `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` and `FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)` ?